# TreeView checkboxes to work as individual & separate checkboxes in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, treeview, unique

I need to have 7 nodes and inside each nearly 30-40 child nodes. Each child-node need to have a 'function body' of it's own, like we can have for a normal single checkbox while working in Form1 in C#. so that I can have freedom to assign it unique task (like fetching unique data, string concatenation and also parsing values to another function). I need to have access to each checkbox basically. 
What so far I tried after creating tree-list was (showing just few lines for simplicity):

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Session");
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Reset");

treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Extended Start");
treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("Hard Reset");
treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("EOL Mode State Read");
treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("Current Err Tracer Read");
treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("Read Odometer value from Bus Read");
```

This generates tree-view GUI like I need but accessing check-boxes is my main question!

Thanks

Comment: What technology are you using? WinForms/ASP/WPF/UWP?

Comment: I'm using WinForms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may define your custom tree node with a delegate property containing some code to perform your tasks, e.g.:

```
class ActionNode : TreeNode
{
    public Action Action { get; }
    public ActionNode(string text, Action action)
        : base(text)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Then add instances of this class as sub-nodes assigning concrete task code to each instance. For example:

```
treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new ActionNode("Extended Start",
    () => { MessageBox.Show("Extended Start"); }));
treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(new ActionNode("Hard Reset",
    () => { MessageBox.Show("Hard Reset"); }));
treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add(new ActionNode("EOL Mode State Read",
    () => { MessageBox.Show("EOL Mode State Read"); }));
treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add(new ActionNode("Current Err Tracer Read",
    () => { MessageBox.Show("Current Err Tracer Read"); }));
treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add(new ActionNode("Read Odometer value from Bus Read",
    () => { MessageBox.Show("Read Odometer value from Bus Read"); }));
```

(NB: the top level nodes implementation may be left as is.)

Then you can use your nodes to access unique task code like this:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    var actionNode = e.Node as ActionNode;
    if (actionNode != null)
        actionNode.Action();
}
```

Comment: Looks right but maybe I'm not following correctly the part where I can use nodes to access unique task code, Can you please just show one example let's say for Node "Session" sub-Node "Extended Start"? would be really helpful of you

Comment: OK. First, place the `ActionNode` class definition (i.e. `class ActionNode :  TreeNode ...`) somewhere in you form class definition. (To be continued...)

Comment: Second, in the method containing your sample code (i.e. lines starting with `treeView1.Nodes.Add("Session");`) remove all lines like `treeView1.Nodes[...].Nodes.Add(...)` and instead put lines from my second code block (i.e. `treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new ActionNode("Extended Start", () => { MessageBox.Show("Extended Start"); }));`)

Comment: Then double click on your `treeView1` control in Form Designer. VS will create an empty `treeView1_AfterSelect` method where you can put lines `var actionNode = e.Node as ActionNode;
    if (actionNode != null)
        actionNode.Action();`

Comment: Run your application and expand and select various nodes in the tree view. You'll see message boxes with unique task messages

Comment: Okay, got that man! Now whatever I want this checkbox to perform I can do it in these declaring parenthesis { MessageBox.Show("Extended Start"); }, correct?

Comment: That's fine, it may be in a button click event handler. At least technically -- the proper place depends on your requirements (for example, if your note set is not dynamic, it's better put it in some initialisation methos), but for tests it's OK.

Comment: Yes, exactly! This `() => {...}` construct is called a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). It is automatically cast to the `Action` delegate type.

Comment: If your unique task code is short enough, you should be fine putting the whole code block within the curly braces of the lambdas. But if the code is long enough you may want to move it in separate methods for the sake of readability.

Comment: If the latter is the case and you've got some method like this: `void HugeTaskCode() { MessageBox.Show("task code"); }`, then you can assign this method to your `ActionNode.Action` property: `treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new ActionNode("Extended Start", HugeTaskCode));`. Mind the method signature though.

Comment: I guess this is exactly what I needed, method to be called from parenthesis becuase the code inside is indeed big enough. Thanks a lot Dmitry! You really helped a lot

Comment: Welcome! Note that you can even omit the whole `() => { ... }` lambda and place only your method name (without parenthesis to reference the method instead of getting it invoked immediately). But your method signature should agree with the `Action` declaration.